# Remove an overlay in mapKit Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, overlay

I'm trying to delete an overlay that is in a mapView

i try this :

myLocation is the mapView

```
        let overlays = myLocation.overlays
        myLocation.removeOverlays(overlays)
```

and this :

```
        var polyline : MKPolyline = MKPolyline()    
        myLocation.removeOverlay(polyline)
```

but both don't work for me :C

anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 2):

Try `mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)`. You can also tag specific overlays and loop through them to remove specific ones.

Comment: It doesn't work for me bro :C could u show me how to loop it to remove a specific one?

Answer (score 2):

//add overlay:

`let polyline: MKPolyline = MKPolyline()
polyline.tag = 100 //any number that you will use to identify this overlay
mapView.addOverlay(polyline)`

//delete overlay:

`for overlay in mapView.overlays {
        if (overlay.tag == 100) {
            mapView.removeOverlay(overlay)
        }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
self.mapView.overlays.forEach {
        if ($0 is MKPolyline) {
            self.mapView.removeOverlay($0)
        }
    }
```